# Using datepicker in the filter section of JQUERY TABLESORTER

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have the following codes. How can I use the date picker in this first field?
If I remove the filter selector it doesn't work. Can anyone help me regarding this issue? I will use it in the APP Script section. https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Widget-options   I tried the codes but unfortunately it didn't work.

```
<div id="rowdata"></div>

    <script>
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( "#format" ).on( "change", function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
});
});

    $( document ).ready(function() {
      getData();
    });



    function getData() 
    {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
      {
        console.log(ar);
        var displayfooter = "<tfoot>";
        displayfooter += "<tr class=\"dark-row\">";
        displayfooter += "<th colspan=\""+ar[0].length+"\">";
          displayfooter += "<div class=\"pager\">";
            displayfooter += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"first\" ><<</button>";
            displayfooter += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"prev\"><</button>";
            displayfooter += "<span class=\"pagedisplay\"></span>";
            displayfooter += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"next\">></button>";
            displayfooter += "<button type=\"button\" class=\"last\">>></button>";
            displayfooter += "<select class=\"pagesize\" title=\"Select page size\">";
              displayfooter += "<option value=\"10\">10</option>";
              displayfooter += "<option value=\"20\">20</option>";
              displayfooter += "<option value=\"30\">30</option>";
              displayfooter += "<option value=\"40\">40</option>";
            displayfooter += "</select>";
            displayfooter += "<select class=\"gotoPage\" title=\"Select page number\"></select>";
          displayfooter += "</div>";
        displayfooter += "</th>";
        displayfooter += "</tr>";
        displayfooter += "</tfoot>";


        var displaybody = "<tbody>";
        ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
        {
          if(index == 0)
          {
            displayheader = "<thead>";
            displayheader += "<tr>";
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false datepicker'> Ziyaret Tarihi    </th>";
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Ziyaret Saati    </th>";
            displayheader += "<th class='filter-select filter-exact sorter-false' data-placeholder='Personel Seçin'> Personel Seçimi     </th>";
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Müşteri Cari İsmi    </th>"; 
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Müşteri Telefon Numarası         </th>";  
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Müşteri Yetkilisi İsmi       </th>";  
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Firma Yetkilisi Ünvan        </th>";  
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Bölge    </th>";  
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Değerlendirme        </th>";  
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Karar    </th>";  
            displayheader += "<th class='sorter-false'> Kartvizit Resmi  </th>";  
            displayheader += "</tr>";
            displayheader += "</thead>";
          }
          else if(index > 0)
          {
            displaybody += "<tr>";
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[0]+"</td>";
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[1]+"</td>";  
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[2]+"</td>";  
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[3]+"</td>";  
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[4]+"</td>"; 
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[5]+"</td>"; 
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[6]+"</td>"; 
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[7]+"</td>"; 
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[8]+"</td>"; 
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[9]+"</td>"; 
            displaybody += "<td>"+item[10]+"</td>"; 
            displaybody += "</tr>";
          }    
        });
        displaybody += "</tbody>";

        var displayTable = '';
        displayTable += "<table id=\"mainTable\" class=\"tablesorter\" >";
        displayTable += displayheader;
        displayTable += displayfooter;
        displayTable += displaybody;
        displayTable += '</table>';     
        document.getElementById("rowdata").innerHTML = displayTable;

        $("#mainTable").tablesorter({
          theme: 'metro-dark',
          sortList: [[0,0]],
          widthFixed: true,
          widgets: ['zebra', 'columns', 'filter','stickyHeaders']

        })
        
        .tablesorterPager({
        // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
        container: $(".pager"),
        output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})'
        
        });

      }).getRecords();
    }

    </script>
```